# How to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 using an USB?

Tags: 12.04, installation, upgrade

I wanted to remove ubuntu but now I just love it!
I want to update my ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.04 LTS using an USB. If you could tell me the steps it would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Is this an WUBI install? Did you install Ubuntu from inside Windows?

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade using a USB stick? It will be much easier to have Ubuntu upgrade itself without.

Answer (score 1):

Run Update Manager - install any updates and rebbot of necessary. Check your settings have Long Term Distributions Upgrades enabled. Check for update again and you will see "New Ubuntu Release 12.04 Available" - then do an upgrade.